# Trying to copy Range from worksheet into a new workbook. Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, export, export-to-excel

Here is what I have:

```
Sub exportDataAM()
Dim wbS As Workbook, wbT As Workbook
Dim wsS As Worksheet, wsT As Worksheet

Set wbS = ThisWorkbook 'workbook that holds this code
Set wsS = wbS.Worksheets("Recap").Range("A1:R5")

wsS.Copy
Set wbT = ActiveWorkbook 'assign reference asap

Set wsT = wbT.Worksheets("Recap").Range("A1:R5")
wsT.Name = "Recap" 'rename sheet

wbT.SaveAs wbS.Path & "\" & "Recap AM" & Format(Now, " dd-mm-yyyy ") 'save new workbook
End Sub
```

I get a Type mismatch which just doesn't make sense to me regarding the .Range on Line 6. I know there are other ways to do this, but this is working fine without the .Range and I wanted to figure out specifically why that may be.

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared the variables `wsS` and `wsT` as Worksheets. Yet, you try adding a range into the variable. This will cause a mismatch.

Either declare the variables as `Range`, or add only the worksheet into the variable.

Comment: Okay, thanks alot for the help. I guess I am still confused.. why can I add .worksheets to the variable wbS but not .range? I figured it was essentially the same thing. Sorry I'm no pro, I am fairly familiar with coding but newer to VB.

The reason I say that is because, Workbook.worksheets().range() works?

Comment: It boils down to your variable declaration.  When you write `Dim wsS as Worksheet`, the system allocates the memory for a Worksheet. When it receives a range instead of a worksheet, it throws an error. Once declared, the variable may use the hierarchy that you've described. You can write `wsS.Range("A1")" without a problem. You just cannot add the range into the variable. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yah it makes sense for sure, I guess the only confusion I have still is why can I add .Worksheets to wbT which has been declared as a workbook?

Sorry to ask probably very obvious questions, but this is really helping me understand the dilemma and I really do appreciate it. 

Should I do something like this

`Set rcS = wsS.Range("A1:E9")`

Comment: Yah I don't know what to try, I've tried a couple of things. I finally got the range to copy into a new workbook only, but then it doesn't have formatting. I'll keep messing with it and checking other posts. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The following should work

```
Private Sub Copy()
Set newBook = Workbooks.Add
With newBook
    .Title = "Recap Am"
    .Subject = "RFQ"
    .SaveAs Filename:="Recap.xls"
  Dim rng As Excel.Range

Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetName").Cells.SpecialCells (xlCellTypeVisible)

rng.Copy newBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

End With
End Sub
```